# Does an answer that ignores major details in a question deserve a downvote?

Tags: discussion, voting, etiquette

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248516/mysql-operate-on-many-rows-using-long-list-of-composite-pks/2248553#2248553) to my question on SO, the answerer completely ignored the fact that there are two keys involved, which was VERY clear in my question (though I edited the title after that to add the word "composite"). So not only is his answer wrong, it's stupid, too.

Since I've run into cases lately where I downvoted when evidently I shouldn't have, does this merit a downvote?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say yes, with the caveat that you should add a comment explaining why -- and revisit the answer if it gets edited to be fixed (remember, re-voting is valid after an edit) and upvote it.

Comment: Thanks. I'll take your answer as definitive. :) Someone apparently deleted the answer, though, so no downvote possible now.

Comment: Some people will simply take the lump on the head so they: 1) stepped into a pile of poo they didn't understand (I've done that), or 2) didn't care and walk away - easier than admitting they've made a mistake.